# Ansible variable without quotes

Tags: ansible

To use a variable gathered from json, I need it to be raw, without quotes:

I have

```
ok: [device] => {
    "fact": {
        "int": "7"
    },
}
```

I want

```
ok: [device] => {
    "fact": {
        "int": 7
    },
}
```

The thing is that the quotes are not part of the variable so I cant use `| int` or `| replace` to remove the quotes.

Is there a way ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The result of a [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#) expression is always a string. You can't get an integer. What you really want, I guess, is the value of the attribute *int* in the dictionary *fact* to be an integer. Test the current value, e.g.

```yaml
        - debug:
            var: fact.int
        - debug:
            var: fact.int|type_debug
```

If the value of the attribute *int* is a string you'll get (abridged)

```yaml
  fact.int: '7'
  fact.int|type_debug: AnsibleUnicode
```

You can convert the string to an integer, e.g.

```yaml
        - set_fact:
            fact: "{{ fact|combine({'int': _int|int}) }}"
          vars:
            _int: "{{ fact.int }}"
        - debug:
            var: fact.int
        - debug:
            var: fact.int|type_debug
```

you'll get (abridged)

```yaml
  fact.int: '7'
  fact.int|type_debug: int
```

Now, the value of the attribute *int* is an integer. But, the result of the Jinja expression `var: fact.int` is still a string `fact.int: '7'`.

---

**Notes**

- Be aware that the [var](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html#parameter-var) option of the [debug](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html#ansible-builtin-debug-print-statements-during-execution) module already runs in Jinja2 context and has an implicit {{ }} wrapping.